# RESTeasy client : send xml data POST = unexpected element (uri="", local="paint")

Tags: xml, inheritance, post, jaxb, resteasy

I want to send a serialized object to the server via a POST request.

```java
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setYear(2010);
        paint.setTitle("title");


        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Paint.class, Art.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        java.io.StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(paint, sw);

        ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:8080/rest/createArt");

        request.body("application/xml", sw.toString());

        ClientResponse<Response> response = request.post(Response.class);
```

For this simple service :

```java
@POST
@Path("/createArt")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public Response createArt(Art a){
    artDAO.createArt(a);
    return Response.ok(a).build();
}
```

but i get the following error :

```
DefaultClientConnection:249 - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 400 javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"paint"). Expected elements are <{}art>, <{}photo>
```

Why theses classes ?

Art.java : abstract class

```java
@Entity @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "art")
public abstract class Art {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
private int id;

@OneToMany (mappedBy="art",cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<Photo> photo;
...
}
```

Paint.java : inherits from Art

```java
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "paint")
public class Paint extends Art{
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private SupportArt support;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) 
private Realisation realisation;
...
}
```

Photo.java

```java
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "photo")
public class Photo {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
private int id;

@ManyToOne 
@JoinColumn (name="art_id")
private Art art;

private String path;
...
}
```

I don't understand my error, i think it's a problem with JAXB annotations.
Inheritance causes me some troubles also.
There a bidirectional relation between Photo and Art, when i delete it, photo is not in the expected elements anymore (it lasts <{}art>).

I have searched on the web and tried a lot of things but it has not solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error, i just had to use XmlSeeAlso :

Art.java : abstract class

```java
@Entity @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@XmlSeeAlso(Paint.class)
public abstract class Art {
```

Had to modify this line too :

```java
ClientResponse<String> response = request.post(String.class);
```